# Passing a partial field list from class to a method

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am attempting to build a function that will accept a typed field list from a class in order to operate on those fields later in the function.

Something along the lines of...

```
const useEntitiy = <T extends Entity>(fields: T.fields[]): T
```

My Entity class and it's implementations might look something like...

```
export default abstract class Entity {
  readonly id?: string
}

class Foo extends Entity {
  readonly id: string
  readonly bar: string
}

class Fuzz extends Entity {
  readonly id: string
  readonly bazz: string
  readonly buzz: string
}
```

With all that defined, I'm hoping to be able to call the above method like so and have it be appropriately type checked.

```
useEntity<Fuzz>(["id", "bazz"])
useEntity<Fuzz>(["id", "buzz"])
useEntity<Foo>(["id", "bar"])
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keyof` operator to get all possible keys of a type. Therefore, you can simply replace `T.fields` in your example with `(typeof T)`:

```
const useEntity = <T extends Entity>(fields: (keyof T)[]): T => {
    ...
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to add more strictness and only return the fields that are applicable, you can use a bit of a more advanced definition:

```
const useEntity = <T extends Entity>() => <K extends keyof T>(fields: K[]): {
    [key in (typeof fields)[number]]: T[key];
} => ({} as any);

const abc = useEntity<Fuzz>()(["id", "buzz"]);

// Type reported by intellisense
const abc: {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly buzz: string;
}
```

Notice that we need an extra call in there, as TypeScript still doesn't allow [partial generic interference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), meaning we need to "split" the definition like this to make it happen.

I played around a bit and see if I could make TS "guess" the entity type solely based on the given key array *(and a type to tell TS "this are the possible types you can get keys from")*, but no luck.